# С какого фреймворк стоит начать ?

Tags: фреймворк, php

С какого фреймворка вы по рекомендуете начать ?

Я так понимаю, оптимальный вариант для начала - будет CodeIgniter или kohana3? Но я могу ведь и ошибаться. По скольку не особо в них разбираюсь. Поэтому прошу помочь советом.

Comment: @Родион Поляков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привожу ссылки, где указано сравнение различных характеристик популярных фреймворков.

[Сравнение популярных PHP-фреймворков](http://www.cmsmagazine.ru/library/items/programming/php-frameworks-compare/)

[Файловая структура](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/08/04/php-applications-where-is-the-include-coming-from/)

[Benchmark](http://www.ruilog.com/blog/view/b6f0e42cf705.html)

Думаю, данная информация Вам должна помочь в выборе.

P.S. Скажу за себя. Yii для меня предпочтительнее других, но я ни в коем случае не навязываю своё мнение, ибо необходимо попробовать каждый (сделать небольшой проект).

Answer (score 3):

Я бы посоветовал начать с `Code Igniter`, он проще, а потом перейти на `Yii`. Опять же, вопрос предпочтений. Данный вопрос не имеет четкого ответа.

Comment: CodeIgniter позволит вам быстро разобраться в сути фреймворков (т.к. он один из самых легких), а затем переходите на потяжелее. 
p.s. легкий не значит плохой :)

Comment: И причем с очень хорошей русской доккументацией

Answer (score 2):

PHP only? Тогда посмотрите еще в сторону [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/). Если нет, то советую мегапоплярный Ruby in Rails или Django / Flask в зависимости от языка.

Comment: Нужно что то хорошо функциональное, но и не слишком замудреное. )
С хорошей документацией на русском языке.

Comment: Тогда (если Вам не важен язык, то используйте Django ([DJBook](http://djbook.ru/)))

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, Django на Python-е, а человека интересует на PHP

Comment: Django сейчас переживает довольно болезненный переход с Python 2.x на 3, с нуля не зная языка и фремворка мне кажется тяжело будет (нынешний 1.5RC вроде бы еще не полностью совместим с 3 Python) вот когда 1.6 выйдет мне кажется логичнее будет с нуля именно его ковырять. А пока просто Python подучить.

Comment: @Deonis первоначально в вопросе не был указан язык, тег php появился позже

Comment: Python я вообще не знаю. 
Мне нужен PHP фреймворк.

Comment: правильное название - Ruby On Rails, просто чтобы не вводить в заблуждение человека)